# Python rq module: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '__module__'

Tags: python, flask, queue, attributeerror, rq

I am trying to test post requests to a Flask server, with a queue generated with rq module.
Rq's queue keeps prompting this weird error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dor/Documents/workspace/NErlNet/src_py/apiServerNew/TotallyNew/test2.py", line 14, in <module>
    result2 = trans.testQueue(baseReceiverAddress + '/testQueue')
  File "/home/dor/Documents/workspace/NErlNet/src_py/apiServerNew/TotallyNew/transmitter.py", line 23, in testQueue
    result = globe.queue.enqueue(testPost(address, 0), args=[])
  File "/home/dor/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/queue.py", line 500, in enqueue
    on_failure, pipeline, args, kwargs) = Queue.parse_args(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dor/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/queue.py", line 466, in parse_args
    if not isinstance(f, string_types) and f.__module__ == '__main__':
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

I'd be happy to get help with this error. These are my files:
transmitter.py:

```
import requests
import globalVars as globe
import queue
from threading import Thread
import redis
from rq import Queue
import time

#DEFAULT_PORT = 8095

def testPost(address, payloadNum):
    payload = {'test' : payloadNum}
    response = requests.post(address,data = payload)
    #Return true, if received: HTTP status code < 400
    #Return the HTTP status code for the response
    #Return the reponse in JSON format
    return(response.ok, response.status_code, response.json())

def testQueue(address):
        result = globe.queue.enqueue(testPost(address, 0), args=[])

def wait():
    while not globe.ackQueue.empty(): #While the queue is NOT empty
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('transmitter')
```

recieverServer.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import globalVars as globe
import redis
from rq import Queue
import queue

receiver = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(receiver)

def runReceiver():
    receiver.run(debug=True, threaded=False)

class test(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return {'Test' : 'Passed!'} #Returns the response in JSON format

class testQueue(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return {'Test' : 'Passed!'} 

#Listener Server list of resources: 
api.add_resource(test, "/test")
api.add_resource(testQueue, "/testQueue")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    runReceiver()
```

globalVars.py

```
import redis
from rq import Queue

r = redis.Redis()
queue = Queue(connection=r)
```

test2.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import transmitter as trans
import receiverServer as receiver
import globalVars as globe

defAddress = 'https://httpbin.org/post' #httpbin is a website aimed for testing HTTP requests
baseReceiverAddress = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result1 = trans.testPost(baseReceiverAddress + '/test', 0)
    print(result1)
    
    result2 = trans.testQueue(baseReceiverAddress + '/testQueue')
    print(result2)
```

I tried to change the testPost function several times, but the error keeps appearing...
Please help me to resolve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

This `globe.queue.enqueue(testPost(address, 0), args=[])` should probably be this: `globe.queue.enqueue(testPost, args=[address, 0])`. Currently you are running the function and passing the results to the queue. What you want to be doing it passing the function, and the arguments you want it to be called with to the queue.

Comment: It doesn't work.... says: TypeError: testPost() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'address' and 'payloadNum'

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the code you have provided. I did get that it doesn't like enqueuing functions that were defined in the `__main__` module. They need to be defined elsewhere, and then imported.